# group by - with distinct results incl. count

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, distinct

Short question about the statement "group by" in mysql:

My current db structure looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE TableName 
    (
     ID int primary key, 
     name varchar(255),
     number varchar(255)
    );

INSERT INTO TableName
(ID, name, number)
VALUES
    (1, "Test 1", "100000"),
    (2, "Apple", "200000"),
    (3, "Test 1 beta", "100000"),
    (4, "BLA", "300000"),
    (5, "ABU", "400000"),
    (6, "CBA", "700000"),
    (7, "ABC", "600000"),
    (8, "Orange - Test", "400000"),
    (9, "ABC", "");
```

My current statement looks like:

```
SELECT name, number, count(*) as Anzahl 
FROM TableName 
group by name,number
```

with this statement the result looks like:

```
NAME            NUMBER      ANZAHL
ABC                     1
Test 1          100000      2
Apple           200000      1
BLA             300000      1
ABU             400000      2
ABC             600000      1
CBA             700000      1
```

But the value "ABC" wouldn't merged.

the result should look like:

```
NAME            NUMBER      ANZAHL
Test 1          100000      2
Apple           200000      1
BLA             300000      1
ABU             400000      2
ABC             600000      2
CBA             700000      1
```

Any Ideas how it could work?

**SQLFiddle:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dcbee/1

the solution must be performant for something like +1 000 000 rows

Answer (score 0):

First of all IMHO, it's a bad design to store numbers into character column. Working with integers is faster than characters. Being said that, I assume all values in name column will be numbers. Here's is a query to avoid multiple ABC values

```
SELECT name, 
       SUM(convert(number, SIGNED INTEGER)) as number, 
       count(*) as Anzahl 
FROM TableName 
GROUP BY name ;
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. i would like to merge name and numbers, with your solution it only merge the name's. the numbers aren't effect.

Comment: @user2908141 learn SQL.. merge (GROUP BY) on name (because you want to have an unique "ABC")  SUM all numbers (sum merge all records) based on name..

Comment: @user2908141 Where do you see only names merging and numbers not merging? Add 

    ORDER BY number

and see data as you explained in your initial question. Also, you have slightly different data on sqlfiddle than explained in your question. For ex, sqlfiddle has "Orange - Test" but your question has no reference of it. I think my query is giving you what you are expecting. You have "Test 1" and "Test 1 Beta" on sqlfiddle but your question final output is expecting count of 2 for "Test 1". How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I suggest  (SQL Fiddle Link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6f83b/5/0)

1. Like @Parag said, I strongly urge you to changed the table definition
2. Then the SQL is easy:

   SELECT name, number, COUNT(*) AS anzahl
     FROM tablename
   WHERE number IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY name, number

Comment: Hi, the result should look like: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dcbee/28 - are there any performance hints/tips?

Comment: Why are you excluding ""Orange - Test", "400000"" from your results, only because it "400000" appears under "ABU", "400000")? Performance is a biggie when doing string vs integer comparison.. Obviously you understand the data much better than I, but this is my interpretation of the code: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6f83b/11/0